# How do I Rank column in SQL based on row day-difference and partition?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get RANK() on a column based on a row difference < 3.

```
select hotel.*,
IFNULL(datediff(visit_date, lag(visit_date)
OVER (partition by hotel_id)), 0) as diff
from hotel;
```

I get the following output,

```
hotel_id customer_id  visit_date  diff
1            1        2020-01-01    0
1            2        2020-01-03    2
2            1        2020-01-01    0
2            2        2020-01-10    9
2            3        2020-01-14    4
3            1        2020-01-04    0
3            1        2020-01-11    7
```

> I am stuck with the RANK() part.

**Expected Output:
If Day Difference is less than 3 then 1 else 2. And if the next one is greater than 3 days the 3, and so on**

```
hotel_id customer_id  visit_date  rank
1            1        2020-01-01    1
1            2        2020-01-03    1
2            1        2020-01-01    1
2            2        2020-01-10    2
2            3        2020-01-14    3
3            1        2020-01-04    1
3            1        2020-01-11    2
```

Comment: You say "If Day Difference is less than 3 then 1 else 2" but the last entry in your table has `rank = 3` how does that work?

Comment: @Nick It is my SQL.
Also, yes! If Day Difference is less than 3 then 1 else 2, 3, 4 and so on. The increase in rank happens only when day diff is not less than 3

Comment: So what happens if the diff goes back down to < 3, is the rank supposed to start counting up again from 2 after that?

Comment: @Nick When rank = 3, and the next customer_id  day difference < 3 then Rank still remains 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to generate your `rank` values. It uses a couple of `CTE`s, the first to generate row numbers for each visit (on a per-hotel basis), and the second (recursive) `CTE` to generate the `rank` values, iterating through the rows from the first `CTE` and only incrementing the `rank` when the difference in dates is more than 2 days:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hotel_rows AS (
  SELECT hotel_id, customer_id, visit_date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hotel_id ORDER BY visit_date) AS rn
  FROM hotel
  ORDER BY hotel_id, visit_date
),
ranks AS (
  SELECT hotel_id, customer_id, visit_date, rn, 1 AS `rank`
  FROM hotel_rows
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT h.hotel_id, h.customer_id, h.visit_date, h.rn,
         r.rank + (h.visit_date > r.visit_date + INTERVAL 2 DAY)
  FROM hotel_rows h
  JOIN ranks r ON h.hotel_id = r.hotel_id
              AND h.rn = r.rn + 1
)
SELECT SELECT hotel_id, customer_id, visit_date, `rank`
FROM ranks
ORDER BY hotel_id, visit_date
```

Output (for my slightly extended demo):

```
hotel_id    customer_id     visit_date  rank
1           1               2020-01-01  1
1           2               2020-01-03  1
2           1               2020-01-01  1
2           2               2020-01-10  2
2           3               2020-01-14  3
2           1               2020-01-15  3
2           2               2020-01-20  4
3           1               2020-01-04  1
3           1               2020-01-11  2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gpVhAj7rWvy9tTcNt4Ut6h/1)

Comment: Correction. If Day Difference is less than 3 then 1 else 2, 3, 4 and so on. The increase in rank happens only when day diff is not less than 3

Comment: @AmoghKatwe please see my edit. I think that will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result as per your given condition then you can try below in SQL Server. here is the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a9d7b1/15)

```
select
  hotel_id, 
  customer_id, 
  visit_date,
  case 
    when days < 3 then 1
    else 2
  end as rnk
from
(
  select
    *,
    datediff(day, n_date, visit_date) as days
  from
  (
      select
        *,
        coalesce(lag(visit_date) over (partition by hotel_id order by visit_date), visit_date) as n_date

      from hotel
  ) val
)days
```

Answer (score 0):

I would express this as:

```
select h.*,
       (case when lag(visit_date) over (partition by hotel_id order by visit_date) < visit_date - interval 3 day
             then 2 else 1
       end)
from hotel h;
```

Edit;

Based on your revised point, you want to assign groups based on the date difference and then use `row_number()`:

```
select h.*,
       1 + sum( coalesce(visit_date > prev_vd + interval 3 day, 0) ) over (partition by hotel_id order by visit_date) as grp
from (select h.*,
             lag(visit_date) over (partition by hotel_id order by visit_date) as prev_vd
      from hotel h
     ) h;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=4c5c488606d3ad7ccc4656655f9dcb16) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Correction. If Day Difference is less than 3 then 1 else 2, 3, 4 and so on. The increase in rank happens only when day diff is not less than 3

Comment: @AmoghKatwe . . . That clarifies a lot -- i see you edited the question.  I *strongly* recommend window functions over recursive CTEs for this type of problem.

Comment: Your approach is partly right. Except, when the value needs to be 1, it's 0, and it's 1 when its supposed to be 2

Comment: @AmoghKatwe . . . I fixed it -- the answer is simpler than I thought -- and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what's the reason for your recommendation? the recursive CTE for this question should be quite efficient since each row can only `JOIN` one other, where your `SUM() OVER...` requires scanning the table with a date comparison for every output row.

Comment: @Nick . . . I am actually a fan of recursive CTEs -- and they have reasonable performance.  That said, built-in functions such as window functions should have much better performance.  In this case, the code is also *much* simpler.

Comment: Definitely agree with you on the "simpler" part. I did a bit of testing with some random data (10000 entries) and it seems the CTE is actually somewhat faster for this particular example. Probably in the noise though.